# Find all nodes where property does NOT match condition

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, where-clause

I'm trying to find a way of returning nodes where the value or a property does not meet a certain condition.

I tried to create a query that will check whether there are any nodes that don't match the nodes in my database (if one has been created on bloom on via the Neo4j browser). The query should delete any nodes that aren't in the DB. I want it to do this by checking whether the nodeId exists on a node in the database.

```
        try {
            const result = await neo4j.executeCypherWriteQuery(
                `
                        MATCH (node:Node)
                        WHERE NOT node.nodeId = $nodeId
                        DELETE node
                        `,
                { nodeId: node.nodeId }
            );
            const singleRecord = result.records[0];
            console.log(`Removed unwanted nodes`, singleRecord?.get(0));
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`Error: ${e}`);
     }
}
```

This query attempts to delete all nodes and not the ones where $nodeId !== and existing nodeId. Is what I am trying to do possible with a cypher query?

Comment: Maybe you have a problem of comparing a string to an integer or a float? The cypher query looks fine

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to run this in a for loop? If so that would explain the behavior: with each iteration you would be firing a query: "delete all nodes exception the one with this specific id". All it requires is two separate runs on two different ids for it delete everything.

If you have a list of ids and want to delete only nodes without those ids, there's a better (and correct) way to do this: pass in the list of ids, MATCH to the nodes with those ids and collect them, then MATCH to all nodes that aren't in that list and delete those:

```
MATCH (node:Node)
WHERE node.nodeId IN $nodeIds // best to have an index on :Node(nodeId), and make sure you're using the right type between your parameters and the type of the properties
WITH collect(node) as keepNodes
WHERE size(keepNodes) > 0 // to prevent mistakes in the MATCH, which might result in an empty collection, and thus wipe out all your nodes
MATCH (node:Node)
WHERE NOT node IN keepNodes
DETACH DELETE node
```